# What is the difference between Fragment.isVisible() and isVisibleToUser

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I use FragmentPagerAdapter , I have four Fragment ,A,B,C,D.
When it is A ,

in  B onresume,

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    if (LogUtil.isDebugable()) {
        LogUtil.i(TAG, "isVisible()"+isVisible());
    }
}
```

it returns ture , but  in setUserVisibleHint(),

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {

    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        Log.d(TAG, "VisibleToUser");
    }else {
        Log.d(TAG, "unVisibleToUser");
    }
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```

isVisibleToUser returns false...

What is the difference between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are using View Pager, and of course it happens

because whenever you are on a page in view pager, it loads the page next to it as well.

And `isVisible()` will return true, **if fragment has been added, or has its view attached to the window** and `isVisibleToUser` would be true **if this fragment's UI is currently visible to the user**

Comment: Thanks so much , so , if I want to use the ViewPager and Fragment ,and I do not want the B(When it is A in font) to connect to the Internet ,I should do it like this ? private boolean isFirst = true;
 
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
  if (isVisibleToUser && isFirst) {
   doNetWork();
   isFirst = false;
  }
  super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
 }

Comment: @yexiaohu am sorry , i didn't get you

Comment: I am so sorry for my English communication skills, maybe you can give me an example , Fragment A,B,C,D, I only want the Frament connect to th Internet when it is visible to the user ,and only once to connect to the Internet

Comment: guys, I am just wondering based on the definition 'isVisible()' returns true if  fragmen1 added (add method), but fragment 2 or even fragment3 already added, since fragment1 still attached. Is that correct?